# An IF statement right before nested IF-ELSE

Tags: c, if-statement, syntax

My question is regarding whether the below snippet is considered good program structure.

```
if(speed > SPEED_LIMIT)
    printf("Speeding!\n");

if(speed >= 80)
{
    printf("A fine of $%d has been issued!\n", FINE_C);
}
else
    if(speed >= 70)
```

Is it alright to have a Basic `if` statement before then going into a nested `if-else`?

Might be a weird question, only the second week into learning programming and our unit is in C.

Comment: The if-else isn't nested.

Comment: Yes it is and its more of used as "else if(condition)"

Comment: I cut off some of my code just to show the top part, the code goes on through different Fine levels which is nested if-else I think.

Comment: Be that as it may, the code you posted doesn't have the if-else nested in anything. Only the last if is nested.

Comment: Though, it's fine, and produces smaller code (most likely) - a more optimized approach would be to embed the speeding (assuming speed limit is otherwise contained in the if-else if structure) - one less condition to check (print happens either way, I'm assuming)

Comment: @StoryTeller Alright, I'll remember for next time to add the full code. I thought people would see that the code continued into a nested if-else without having to paste a bigger part of it, it's why I included the bottom if.

Comment: You don't always need to add the full code. But the question must be in the terms of the code you have shown, not the code we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, syntactically there's no problem. You can have any number of `if` statement and `if-else` statement next to each other. It is mainly about the readability and maintainability of the code which requires alternate possible approaches.

For example, a better "grouping" would be

```
if (more than limit)
{
    if (more than higher limit) {...}
    else if (more than middle limit) {...}
    else {....}
}
else
{
    //normal
}
```

over

```
if (more than limit) {...}
if (more than higher limit) {...}
else if (more than middle limit) {...}
else if {some other condition}
else
{
    //normal
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I hadn't known about the else if. It's only our second lab and I think the tutor is more looking for readability, I did find some of these alternative methods when I searched but I think he might want us to stick to the concepts we've learnt so far because everything is so new. It's why I was wondering the question. 

The responses are so fast here...it's crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you see it quite a lot. However, the normal way to format it is not to add an additional level of indenting and it is normal to put the else and the if on the same line. This is so you can have as many of these as you like without going off the right hand side of the screen i.e.

```
if(speed >= 80)
{
    printf("A fine of $%d has been issued!\n", FINE_C);
}
else if(speed >= 70)
{ 
    // whatever
}
else if (speed >= 60)
{
    // whatever
}
else if (speed >= 50)
// etc
```

It's like a slightly more flexible version of a switch statement.

**EDIT**

I see I answered the wrong question. The above is all fine, but if you are asking if this is OK

```
if(speed > SPEED_LIMIT)
    printf("Speeding!\n");

if(speed >= 80) ...
```

Then yes, although if the speed limit is more than 80, the logic will be wrong, so it would be better to structure it thus:

```
    if(speed > SPEED_LIMIT)
    {
        printf("Speeding!\n");

        if(speed >= 80) ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is no problem while doing this.Consider these two as separably, No matter what the condition satisfies or not The only thing to notice here is that if first condition is true/false (no matter what) next if will still be executed. If next condition is true then it will be executed then else will be ignored.

Until you want second condition let execute no matter first will be true or false.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily a bad thing, however, being consistent in your code is something you should teach yourself from the beginning of your programming career. :)

All 3 of your ifs for instance can be made in a nested if/else like this, which in my opinion (and a lot of other programmers) looks a lot sleeker.

```
if(speed > SPEED_LIMIT) {
    printf("Speeding!\n");
} else if(speed >= 80) {
    printf("A fine of $%d has been issued!\n", FINE_C);
} else {
    /* whatever happens when speed is greater or equal to 70 /*
}
```

Consistency is quite important in bigger projects. Not only for yourself, but also for your colleagues. When 2 functions for example which do the same thing are written in different ways, it's more work to understand what they do, only to end up realizing they do the same thing. Quite frustrating, no? ;)

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions) you can find some coding conventions which are some guidelines you can follow, ofcourse, your teacher or in the future your company can give you other conventions you have to follow.

Good luck!

Comment: _"All 3 of your ifs for instance can be made in a nested if/else like this, which in my opinion (and a lot of other programmers) looks a lot sleeker."_ No, because you changed the semantics of the program.